# Error in sample / template Azure Bot Framework solution 'EchoBot' without having modified any code

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I have downloaded the Azure 'EchoBot' sample from Azure, using Azure Portal > Create Resource > Web App Bot > V4 Framework > Echo Bot.

I downloaded the resulting scaffolding code, and it seems to have an error already in the sample? I can't fix it myself, because I don't really understand the structure of the code yet. This was to be my learning exercise. It appears to be an error in the dependency injection during startup? I have updated all nuget packages and confirmed that other examples/samples on the net have this same code? (Replacing 'EchoBot' with the name of their solution). Can anyone assist? I can't even build and run the sample with this issue/error.

[image]

Comment: Try `EchoBot.Echobot`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `EchoBot.Echobot`. The error message is telling you that it cannot resolve because you are using a namespace instead of a type. You have two options here:

1) The dirty way - replace `EchoBot` with `EchoBot.EchoBot`. The first `EchoBot` being the namespace, and the second being the class inside that namespace.

2) The nicer way - add `using EchoBot = EchoBot.EchoBot;` at the top of your `Startup.cs` file.

The explanation being that the `EchoBot` class declaration is inside the `EchoBot` namespace - see the `EchoBot.cs` file and you will see `namespace EchoBot` near the top.

Comment: I've actually realised that this error occurs if I try to add any (and I mean ANY) new class to the project. It doesn't matter where, if I add new Class.cs file (to say, add some LUIS logic in) that error comes up. If I remove the class, that error goes away. I haven't seen this type of behaviour before.

Comment: Tried restarting Visual Studio? Mind zipping up the project and posting a link sot hat I can take a look?

Comment: Tried restarting. Same thing. The moment I add a class - just an empty one - the error occurs. Remove the class, error goes away. Here's the project. https://gofile.io/?c=8xKZby

Comment: I get a bad gateway error when I try to visit the link that you provided. In the project that you upload it would be good to have one of these new classes that you have added and a comment on the line where you are getting the error (along with the exact error message itself).

Comment: "Example.cs" class added to project. Error line has been commented with // ERROR HERE. Now uploaded here -> http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=95129956869843040827

Comment: And the error is 'EchoBot' is a namespace but is used as a type. But this only happens if I try to add a new class anywhere in the project (in my use case, to add LUIS functionality)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your chat invitation. I 'solved' this issue without really solving it as such. I just created a new template from Azure using the LUIS template instead of the echo bot. The new template doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: Haha nice. The classic reboot option.

Comment: I am now however completely lost in a haze of stuff-ups with how i expect WaterFall dialogs to behave, so am posting a new question on that. I haven't touched bots since V3 and everything has changed. I'm creating rubbish when I want something to work that in my mind is quite simple lol. Ah well.